# array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array(one to one relation update)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, controller, relation

```html
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('profile.update') }}">
    @csrf
    <div class="card card-primary">
    <div class="card-header">
        <h3 class="card-title">
        <i class="fas fa-text-width"></i>
        Description
        </h3>
    </div>
    <!-- /.card-header -->
    <div class="card-body">
        <dl class="row">
        <dt class="col-sm-4">Nama</dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-6"><input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="{{ $user->name }}" placeholder="Masukkan Data Anda"></dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-4">NIP</dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-6"><input type="text" name="nip" class="form-control" value="{{ $user->nip }}" placeholder="Masukkan Data Anda"></dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-4">NUPTK</dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-6"><input type="text" name="nuptk" class="form-control" value="{{ $user->profile->nuptk }}" placeholder="Masukkan Data Anda"></dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-4">Nomor Seri KARPEG</dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-6"><input type="text" name="no_seri_karpeg" class="form-control" value="{{ $user->profile->no_seri_karpeg }}" placeholder="Masukkan Data Anda"></dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-4">Pangkat / Golongan Ruang / TMT</dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-2">
            <select name="pangkat" class="form-control" value="{{ $user->profile->pangkat }}">
                <option value="">Pilih Data</option>
                <option value="Penata Muda">Penata Muda</option>
                <option value="Penata Muda Tk.I">Penata Muda Tk.I</option>
                <option value="Penata">Penata</option>
                <option value="Penata Tk.I">Penata Tk.I</option>
                <option value="Pembina">Pembina</option>
                <option value="Pembina Tk.I">Pembina Tk.I</option>
                <option value="Pembina Utama Muda">Pembina Utama Muda</option>
                <option value="Pembina Utama Madya">Pembina Utama Madya</option>
                <option value="Pembina Utama">Pembina Utama</option>
            </select>
        </dd>
        <dd class="col-sm-2">
            <select name="golongan" class="form-control" value="{{ $user->profile->golongan }}">
                <option value="">Pilih Data</option>
                <option value="III">III</option>
                <option value="IV">IV</option>
            </select>
        </dd>
        <dd class="col-sm-2">
            <select name="golongan" class="form-control" value="{{ $user->profile->ruang }}">
                <option value="">Pilih Data</option>
                <option value="a">a</option>
                <option value="b">b</option>
                <option value="c">c</option>
                <option value="d">d</option>
                <option value="e">e</option>
            </select>
        </dd>
        <dd class="col-sm-2">
            <input type="text" name="tmt_pangkat" class="form-control" value="{{ $user->profile->tmt_pangkat }}" placeholder="Masukkan Data Anda">
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-4">Jabatan / TMT</dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-3">
            <select name="jabatan" class="form-control" value="{{ $user->profile->jabatan }}">
                <option value="">Pilih Data</option>
                <option value="Guru Pertama">Guru Pertama</option>
                <option value="Guru Muda">Guru Muda</option>
                <option value="Guru Madya">Guru Madya</option>
                <option value="Guru Utama">Guru Utama</option>
            </select>
        </dd>
        <dd class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" name="tmt_jabatan" class="form-control" value="{{ $user->profile->tmt_jabatan }}" placeholder="Masukkan Data Anda">
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-4">Tempat dan Tanggal Lahir</dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" name="" class="form-control" value="{{ $user->profile->tempat_lahir }}" placeholder="Masukkan Data Anda"></dd>
        <dd class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" name="" class="form-control" value="{{ $user->profile->tanggal_lahir }}" placeholder="Masukkan Data Anda"></dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-4">Jenis Kelamin</dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-6"><input type="text" name="" class="form-control" value="{{ $user->jk }}" placeholder="Masukkan Data Anda"></dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-4">Pendidikan Tertinggi</dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-3">
            <select name="pendidikan_jurusan" class="form-control" value="{{ $user->profile->pendidikan_jurusan }}">
                <option value="">Pilih Data</option>
                <option value="SD">SD</option>
                <option value="SMP">SMP</option>
                <option value="SMA/SMK">SMA/SMK</option>
                <option value="D-I">D-I</option>
                <option value="D-II">D-II</option>
                <option value="D-IV">D-IV</option>
                <option value="S-I">S-I</option>
                <option value="S-II">S-II</option>
                <option value="S-III">S-III</option>
            </select>
        </dd>
        <dd class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" name="pendidikan_jurusan" class="form-control" value="{{ $user->profile->pendidikan_jurusan }}" placeholder="Masukkan Data Anda"> 
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-4">Jabatan Fungsional / TMT</dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" name="jabatan_fungsional" class="form-control" value="{{ $user->profile->jabatan_fungsional }}" placeholder="Masukkan Data Anda"> 
        </dd>
        <dd class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" name="tmt_jabatan_fungsional" class="form-control" value="{{ $user->profile->tmt_jabatan_fungsional }}" placeholder="Masukkan Data Anda"> 
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-4">Masa Kerja Golongan Lama</dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-6"><input type="text" name="" class="form-control" value="{{ $user->profile->masa_kerja_lama }}" placeholder="Masukkan Data Anda"></dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-4">Jenis Guru</dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-6"><input type="text" name="" class="form-control" value="{{ $user->profile->jenis_guru }}" placeholder="Masukkan Data Anda"></dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-4">Mengajar Kelas</dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-6"><input type="text" name="" class="form-control" value="{{ $user->profile->lama_mengajar }}" placeholder="Masukkan Data Anda"></dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-4">Unit Kerja</dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-6"><input type="text" name="" class="form-control" value="{{ $user->profile->unit_kerja }}" placeholder="Masukkan Data Anda"></dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-4">Gaji Pokok Lama</dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-6"><input type="text" name="" class="form-control" value="{{ $user->profile->gaji_lama }}" placeholder="Masukkan Data Anda"></dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-4">Jabatan/TMT/Jumlah AK Lama</dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-6"><input type="text" name="" class="form-control" value="{{ $user->profile->jumlah_ak_lama }}" placeholder="Masukkan Data Anda"></dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
    <!-- /.card-body -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.card -->
    <div class="card card-primary">
    <div class="card-header">
        <h3 class="card-title">
        <i class="fas fa-text-width"></i>
        Tempat Tinggal
        </h3>
    </div>
    <!-- /.card-header -->
    <div class="card-body">
        <dl class="row">
        <dt class="col-sm-3">Alamat</dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" name="" class="form-control" value="{{ $user->profile->alamat }}" placeholder="Masukkan Data Anda"></dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-3">Provinsi</dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" name="" class="form-control" value="{{ $user->profile->provinsi }}" placeholder="Masukkan Data Anda"></dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-3">Kota</dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" name="" class="form-control" value="{{ $user->profile->kota }}" placeholder="Masukkan Data Anda"></dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-3">Kelurahan</dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" name="" class="form-control" value="{{ $user->profile->kelurahan }}" placeholder="Masukkan Data Anda"></dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-3">Kecamatan</dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" name="" class="form-control" value="{{ $user->profile->kecamatan }}" placeholder="Masukkan Data Anda"></dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-3">Kode Pos</dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" name="" class="form-control" value="{{ $user->profile->kode_pos }}" placeholder="Masukkan Data Anda"></dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
    <!-- /.card-body -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.card -->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Perbaharui Data</button>
</form>
```

Hello guys help me with this error, I was try to update profile table with user relation, i stuck on controller my model was done correctly, can help me. 
there is my view code and my controller page, if you need my model page i will give it later, i only focused on controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $id = null, User $user, Profile $profile)
{
    $userId = $id ?: auth()->user()->id;
    $user = User::with('profile')->findOrFail($userId);

    $request->validate($request->all());

    $user = User::update($request->all());
    $profile= Profile::update($request->all());
    return route('profile')->with('success','Updated');
}
```

[Error Show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IS5l6.png)

Thanks For Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the stacktrace it is related to an error with the validation. The `validate()` method on the request takes validation rule as input, it already has the input in context of the request, so you do not have to pass it.

```
$request->validate([
    'jabatan' => ['required', 'string'],
    // ... more rules
]);
```

If you want everything required you can map each input with map.

```
$rules = array_map(function () {
    return ['required'];
}, $request->all());

$request->validate($rules);
```

Comment: the field, cannot use $request-> all

Comment: Request all is your input, you need to specify how you should validate the input. The request already knows your data, so you do not have to pass it. See the docs https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation

Comment: because all is require

Comment: you will have to specify your rules somehow

Comment: I updated my solution with something to specify your needs, but writing validation is the correct approach as you will have to customize it at some point.

Answer (score 0):

```
$request->validate($request->all(), [
    'field' => 'required'
]);
```

Comment: Provide description what you want to achieve through it.